# How to use PHP with Tailwind CLI?

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I am using the Tailwind CLI installation and all the files work except the PHP files.

So I decided to try adding in my TailwindCSS configuration the `.php` extension and then tried to connect to the page with the Live Server but no the page was not using Tailwind.

Here is my `tailwind.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,php}"],

  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Check out the new answer it might help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i manage to make it work if your `.php` file is located on the root directory your tailwind config must look like this.

```
 /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./*.{html,php}"],
    
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

then on the portion where you have to link your output.css on your `html` head section you must include the `./`

```
<link href="./dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or to validate open your dev tool network tab and check if output.css returns http response 200

Comment: It helped a lot, yes I was using the index in the root directory and did not realize the lack of the `./` Thank you!